# Visual Studio project dependancy question

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, build, pre-build-event

I have a Visual Studio solution with projects `A`, `B`, and `C`.
`A` and `B` are indpendant and should do some task `T` every time they are build. Project `C` is denendant to `A`, `B` and when `C` is built, task `T` should be done as well. For any case it's needed task `T` to be done once.

**First approach:**
I tried to trigger task `T` as pre-build event on projects `A` and `B`. That doesn't work when I build `C` because then `A` and `B` are build in parallel and two instances of task `T` is run in parallel and disturb each other.

**Second approach:**
I want to create new project `D` that will do pre-build event `T`. It will not have C++ or C# sources, just one script to perform `T`. Both `A` and `B` will be dependant to `D`. This solves the issue with paralelism but has other problems with Visual studio logic.

1. Visual Studio will build `D` only when it is outdated but I need it to be run always? Is it possible?
2. When project `D` is built it should not make `A` and `B` outdated.

Can you help to resolve these issues with Second approach or maybe there is better solution?

Comment: Is there no way to modify your task to be idempotent? So that no matter when and how many times you run it, the result will be the same.

Comment: Thats also possible. The task creates a file. I need to syncronise file creation.

Comment: Well it isn't nice and you probably already thought about it, but you can add a dependency between A and B and then they won't disturb each other in you first approach.

Comment: Agree, but those are growing C# pojects and I would like to build them in parallel. Only task `T` part needed to be done once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague suggested to add this to vsxproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <UpToDateCheckInput Include="$(SolutionDir)\a.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

It is path to a nonexisting file `a.txt`. Now it is built every time